# Rails 4 - Should I place logger/debug messages inside a block Rails.env.development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using inside a controller a logger message:

```
logger.debug "Here is the resulting object find_by_sql outputs: #{@deal}"
```

Should I use

```
if Rails.env.development?   
  logger.debug "Here is the resulting object find_by_sql outputs: #{@deal}"
end
```

Is it generally a good practice to put the logger message inside a Rails.dev block? I don't want to slow even a little little bit the app so the fact i add a if/end block will slow the app.

Letting it without any restriction to the dev mode would compromise the information security?

Comment: Your logs are (usually) stored on your host server (the one hosting your app). Unless you have a security breach (an intruder can connect to your server), nobody should be able to read your logs. Also, keep in mind that what you do in development mode is what you **expect** to happen, but in production mode, everything can happen (users do weird stuff sometimes). For this reason I would try to log stuff in production mode because maybe one day something weird and not planned will happen but you won't have a lot of informations about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do that with if statements. It's already controlled by `log_level` of the environment

In your `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

But if you put this into `config/environments/production.rb` (default value, btw), you won't see any debug messages in the production log.

```
 config.log_level = :warn
```

If you want to temporarily increase verbosity of production logs (for debugging or whatever), change log_level and redeploy. Do your troubleshooting and then rollback the app when you're done. Easier than touching `Rails.env` checks all over the codebase, isn't it?